# Singleton in Racket (LISP)

Tags: lisp, racket

I have homeworks to do for Tuesday. It's about Racket. I have to developpe a program that can know if in the list it's a singleton or not.
I'm stuck so i ask u to help me.

Thanks all.

```
  (if (pair? l)
      (if (pair? (cdr l))
                 #f
                 #t))
      #f
      #t
      )
```

Comment: `(pair? (cdr l) #f #t)`, pair? does not take 3 parameters; likewise, if does not take 4 parameters

Comment: ok but look the code it doesnt take 3 parameters

Comment: (if (pair? (cdr l))

Comment: The outermost if is problematic, I thought it was given 4 arg but in fact there is a closing parenthesis too early. Please reformat and indent your code.

Answer (score 1):

A list is a singleton if it contains a single element, so it should be enough if we check that:

1. The object is a pair
2. Its `cdr` is `null`

Like this:

```
(and (pair? l) (null? (cdr l)))
```